# Mobile input cannot be updated programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

So I have an `input[type="number"]` (with preferably a `pattern="[0-9]*"` attribute to bring up the correct keypad in iOS (iPhone, doesn't work on iPad))

When I'm updating the value programmatically, iOS screws it up and Android refuses to work altogether.

I've got a small test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/9QUPe/

Basically, the keypad (on iOS at least) doesn't give you a decimal place, so I want to add that for the user.

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
    var val = this.value.replace('.','');
    if(val.length <= 2){
        this.value = '.'+val
    }else{
        this.value = val.slice(0,-2) +'.'+ val.slice(-2);
    }
});
```

Works perfectly on Chrome (Win7) - but iOS doesn't accept zeros (even though the data is kept as a string) and Android will just empty the input altogether (whether or not the `pattern` attribute is present (see http://jsfiddle.net/9QUPe/1 on Android for this test case)).

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured I can replace `input type="number"` with `input type="tel"` which provides a similar keyboard, and works correctly on iOS/Android - but brings in the additional characters ,;+*#-()N...

So the solution I've come up with is to use `type="tel"` and strip those extra chars.

```
$('input').on('keyup change', function() {
    var val = this.value;
    val = val.replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (val.length <= 2) {
        this.value = '.' + val;
    } else {
        this.value = val.slice(0, -2) + '.' + val.slice(-2);
    }
});​
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/9QUPe/9/)